# Why does int vs bool typecheck fail

Tags: c++

I recently wrongly declared an int as a bool and got no type error from the g++ compiler. Then I tried it again for testing and it compiles fine. Can someone explain why this is acceptable behaviour? Shouldn't the compiler give me a warning at least when i try to `++` a boolean or when i assign a `bool` as `integer`.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool x = 0;
    x++;
    x++;
    cout << x << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bool` is internally implemented as an `int` in C++, and the only allowed values are `1` and `0`.

Comment: @HappyCoder That doesn't sound right. You may be thinking of C.

Comment: Oh yeah. That would be C. In case of C++, implementation varies from compiler-to-compiler

Answer (score 1):

- With the old standards (C++98) it is not an error.
- With the new standards incrementing a boolean is deprecated. (C++11)
- You can use incrementation on a boolean until C++17.